# Could not login in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have just upgraded my operating system Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. But after installing completely, during login I couldn't login even with right password.I checked it was indeed a right password by entering username and password after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, I even changed the password from advanced recovery mode but still new password also doesn't work. For the right password the screen goes black for like a second then again comes back in the same purple login screen but with wrong password it says -sorry, that didn't work. please try again. I am new to Linux and any help is appreciated.

Comment: > pressing Ctrl+Alt+T. Login This key combo doesn't bring up the terminal on a Macbook. I had no option but to delete my installation and start over again.

Comment: I am not a Mac User, but you can bring the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fkeys like Ctrl+Alt+F3 in linux .Give this a try. You can use F1-F6 i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the answer.It worked in my machine as this problem happened again.( But this works if you have more than one account with password known of superuser account and you want to login to another account with no superuser privileges where  you could not login, else refer to @loginbugfixubuntu2004 's answer which could help.)

What I did was:

1.I pressed `Ctrl + Alt + f3` ( you may do any f-keys from f2-f6 )

2.I login with a existing superuser account

3.You may make a home directory of "anotheruser" if no such home directory exists  by:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/anotheruser
```

Then I copied the following files from superuser home directory to the home directory of that user where I could not login.

```
$ sudo cp .bashrc .profile .bash_logout /home/anotheruser
```

4. 

```
  $ cd /home/anotheruser
  $ sudo chown anotheruser: .
  $ sudo chown anotheruser: .bashrc .profile .bash_logout
```

5.then :

```
$ logout
```

6.reboot then hope it will work now

7.If again it does not work then like I tried changing password it may for you too.

8.Again press `Ctrl + Alt + f3` ( or other fkeys as said above)

9.login as superuser

10.Change the password of "anotheruser" by:`$ sudo passwd anotheruser`

11.`$ logout`

12. Reboot and hope it will work now.

Note: This problem may also arise if you make user by `$ sudo useradd newuser`.
Don't do this instead use the `adduser` command.

Comment: I am getting login incorrect on typing password with sudo

Answer (score 8):

It's caused by ticking 'enable automatic logging in' at installation. Open the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T. Login, then enter

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Change AutomaticLoginEnable from true to false, save the file, then reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I reinstalled at that time as I did not get any help at that time and that worked.

Comment: Well this seems like a bad, show stopping bug. That I encountered only 10 minutes after switching back to Linux. Reminds me of every time I've tried Ubuntu for the last 15 years. It's remarkably unstable.

Comment: Omg... I've spent more than an hour reading the same remove .Xauthority, changing owner, user id, etc... but THIS did solve the problem.

Comment: This isn't the issue. And if this wasn't enabled before, it won't be enabled after the upgrade. The problem is most likely due to issues with the video driver, which is causing the windowing manager to crash and bump the user back to the login screen.